# Porting of Qt code on Android and how it works

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, porting

I was thinking of porting my Qt application on android.

My question is how a code written in C++ and Qt which is also a C++ library gets ported to android as android requires java code and an apk file is needed to install the app on device. I am curious as to how and what things they do on the code to make it work like a java code.

If the question is not clear ,  please comment and i will do my best to make it more clear.

Answer (score 6):

Android applications are Java applications, running on a virtual machine called “Dalvik”. This causes many challenges for a  Qt/C++ application to run on such a Java based platform. To ovecome this, a Qt for Android application has two parts. The first part is your Qt/C++ native application which is organized by qmake. The second part is a launcher which is a Java code generated by Qt Creator automatically based on your application preferences, settings and target Android version.

The launcher is a Java process, so Qt Android applications have a Java-based entry point. The Java code in launcher will load the required Qt libraries, based on the meta-information given in other files in the template. So when a Qt for Android application is started, it's just a regular Java application. The entry point will be in `QtActivity.java` which can be found under `android/src/…` in your project build directory.

After loading the Qt libraries, the Java code will start the application's native main() function on a new thread and the application will launch. At this point, the Java code is used to delegate events from Android into Qt. Qt for Android applications use "Java Native Interface" (JNI) to communicate between Java world and C++ world.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this insight.That was really helpful but i cannt upvote as i am new to this. just one more thing,  the part when you said that "second part is launcher which generates java code by Qt creator" .  Just wanted to know what code it generates that lets the communication between the c++ world and java world. Ex.- if i write HelloWorld program in c++ ,  what code will make it callable by the java . Hope i am asking the right question ,  correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @RahulAssassin You can build a simple Qt Android application and see the Java file `QtActivity.java` generated in `$BUILD_TARGET/android/src/...`.

Comment: I made the qt application and can successfully run it on my device but I am not getting a way to change the application image .please help.

Comment: @RahulAssassin You are better to ask it in a new question. Describe the problem and what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Qt5.4.0 and install NDK+android SDK you will find it's very easy that you can use c++ on Android.

Comment: Thanks. I was earlier trying with the Qt 5.1 with no luck. Now i have deleted that and installing Qt 5.4 .  Will let you know if it works but thanks anyways.

Comment: Finally i could run the QT application on my android device..:)